# Keep Table Cell Width fixed when inside an overflow div

Tags: html, css, html-table, width, parent

Please see the code at the bottom of the post.  There is a table inside a div.  When the `$size` variable is small, like 2 or 3, and all the cells can easily fit inside the div, the width of the `<th>` cells are controlled correctly to have width 100px.  If you change the `$size` variable: `$size = 20`, you will see that the table `<th>` cells are squeezed to fit in the div, even though it has an `overflow:auto` property.  I see the same thing for `overflow:scroll`.

What I would like to see is the table cell width remain constant at 100px, and the div introduce a scroll bar to scroll to see all cells.  I do not want the width of the cells shrinking even if the `$size == 1000`.

How to get the table to retain the `width : 100px` even though it is bigger than the parent div?  And have the parent div be scroll-able then.

```
<style type="text/CSS">

    .headrow {
        border : 1px solid;
        width : 100px;
        height : 40px;
    }

table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

</style>


<div id="b" style="border:1px solid;width:585px;height:60px;overflow:auto;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <?php
            $size = 20;
                for ($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
                    echo '<th class="headrow"></th>';
                }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your CSS to this:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/8bCcj/).